# Using prufer correspondence to find number of trees

Tags: graph-theory

> Using the Prufer correspondence, for n ≥ 7, calculate how many trees with vertex set
>   [n] are there that have n − 4 leaves and exactly three vertices of degree two.

So I kind of get how to turn a prufer code into a tree and a tree into a code but I don't understand the generalization of how many trees one can make from given specifications.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll assume, given that you want to solve this using Prüfer sequences, that by “trees” you mean labeled trees.

$n-1$ of the degrees are specified. A tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, so the sum of the degrees is $2n-2$. That determines the last degree to be $(2n-2)-(n-4)-3\cdot2=n-4$.

The degree of a vertex is one more than the number of times its label appears in the Prüfer sequence. Thus there are $n-4$ nodes that don’t appear at all, three that appear once and one that appears $n-5$ times. There are $n$ choices for the vertex that appears $n-5$ times, then $\binom{n-1}3$ choices for the vertices that appear once, and $(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)$ choices for their positions in the Prüfer sequence. Thus there are

$$
n\binom{n-1}3(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)^2(n-4)}6=40\binom n5\binom{n-2}2
$$

labeled trees that satisfy the given conditions.